# How to display validate error - reset password in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.4

I try to catch error message from validate in `.../app/Http/Controllers/Auth/ResetPasswordController.php`:

```
public function reset(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, $this->rules(), $this->validationErrorMessages());

        $response = $this->broker()->reset(
                $this->credentials($request), function ($user, $password) {
            $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
        }
        );

        return $response == Password::PASSWORD_RESET
                ? $this->sendResetResponse($response)
                : $this->sendResetFailedResponse($request, $response);
    }
```

but if the validate failed in session there is no errors.

In:

```
public function validate(Request $request, array $rules, array $messages = [], array $customAttributes = [])
    {
        $validator = $this->getValidationFactory()->make($request->all(), $rules, $messages, $customAttributes);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $this->throwValidationException($request, $validator);
        }
    }
```

throw exception but I do not know how to use it in session.

But if I check `$validator->errors()->getMessages()` in `protected function formatValidationErrors(Validator $validator)` error message exists:

```
array:1 [▼
  "password" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "The password confirmation does not match."
  ]
]
```

**EDITED**

In my case problem was multiple use `StartSession` in `Kernel.php`. After commented `StartSession` in `$middleware` flash in session works good. I do not know how and when it may happend.
From this:

```
protected $middleware = [
            \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\LanguageSwitcher::class,
        ];
```

to this:

```
protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        //\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\LanguageSwitcher::class,
    ];
```

and

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
(...)
```

Comment: Please mention the error also .

Comment: what you  written for displaying message in blade.php file ?

Answer (score 1):

use this code for catch validate errror

```
$this->validate($Request, [
    'Email' => 'required|unique:users',
    'Username' => 'required',
    'Password' => 'required',
    ]);
```

Comment: This didnt catch anything, you need to change `$Request` to `$request` in your answer  though, but its still slipping right by the page, and going right back to the `password/reset` landing page.

Comment: I was able to get it to validate by changing the `Email` to `'email' => 'required'` and commenting Username and Password entrys, that atleast helped me determine which was causing the failure..  So, `dd($this->rules());` shows also token, not username, so i think it must be the token.  This atleast gives me something to go on.

Comment: Edit, ok, i was able to diagnose that its the token, results are this `"_token" => "MzVpGGIhNiVBaRWixxxf4Z0FC7KxxXPVhixAKBmL"
      "token" => null`  For some reason, the token is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your code with following:

```
    $this->validate($request, [
                'token' => 'required',
                'email' => 'required|email|max:35',
                'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6|max:15',
            ]);

            $credentials = $request->only(
                'email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'
            );

            $response = Password::reset($credentials, function ($user, $password) {
                $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
            });
 switch ($response) {
            case Password::PASSWORD_RESET:
                return redirect($this->redirectPath())->with('status', trans($response));

            default:
                return redirect()->back()
                            ->withInput($request->only('email'))
                            ->withErrors(['email' => trans($response)]);
        }
```